# How to prevent scrolling with navigation in angular 17 component?

Tags: angular, angular17

I added this code in `app.config.ts` to scroll to top with every navigation

**app.config.ts**

```
const scrollConfig: InMemoryScrollingOptions = {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
};

const inMemoryScrollingFeature: InMemoryScrollingFeature =
  withInMemoryScrolling(scrollConfig);

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes, inMemoryScrollingFeature),
  ],
};
```

And I need to add, delete query params with typescript like this, but with every change in the query params it scrolls to the top.

**app.component.ts**

```
  addQueryParam(key: string, value: string) {
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: { [key]: value },
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
    });
  }

  deleteQueryParam(key: string) {
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: { ...this.route.snapshot.queryParams, [key]: null },
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
    });
  }
```

How to prevent scrolling if the change is only in query params?